# How to implement a vending machine?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

For a school project I have been asked to create a virtual vending machine in a windows form application using visual basic. I am around 80% complete but I have a few of problems that I have researched multiple times but still cannot find help.

Firstly, on the vending machine when I purchase an item if the credit left over (change) is less than the products originals price it will display an error message saying you do not have enough credit to buy the product. How do I make it so it only displays that message if the credit is not enough to buy the product before-hand and not straight away after the purchase?

Secondly, how would I go about making a system for the credit left over after the purchase, as at the moment I have only got a credit return button which the user would use to extract the remaining credit left over after the purchase, instead of a system for giving out change.

Finally, how would I make it so the user is not allowed to enter text into a text-box as the vending machine uses two text box's, one to display credit and the other to display other general messages such as to clarify that you have bought a certain product or that you do not have enough credit to purchase a certain product.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Galaxy Caramel, Please Insert 60p"
    If credit >= 60 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing a Galaxy Caramel bar"
    credit = credit - 60
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 60 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase a Galaxy Caramel Bar"



End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Cadburys Milk Chocolate, Please Insert 75p"
    If credit >= 75 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing a Cadburys Milk Chocolate Bar"
    credit = credit - 75
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 75 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase a Cadburys Milk Chocolate Bar"
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Bounty, Please Insert 70p"
    If credit >= 70 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing a Bounty bar"
    credit = credit - 70
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 70 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase a Bounty Bar"



End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Yorkie, Please Insert 60p"
    If credit >= 60 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing a Yorkie bar"
    credit = credit - 60
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 60 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase a Yorkie Bar"




End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Doritos Tangy Cheese, Please Insert 85p"
    If credit >= 85 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing Doritos Tangy Cheese Crisps"
    credit = credit - 85
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 85 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit purchase Doritos Tangy Cheese Crisps"



End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Doritos Cool Original, Please Insert 75p"
    If credit >= 75 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing Doritos Cool Original Crisps"
    credit = credit - 75
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 75 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase Doritos Cool Original Crisps"

End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Walkers Cheese & Onion, Please Insert 70p"
    If credit >= 70 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing Walkers Cheese & Onion Crisps"
    credit = credit - 70
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 70 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase Walkers Cheese & Onion Crisps"


End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Mccoy's Cheddar, Please Insert 80p"
    If credit >= 80 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing Mccoy's Cheddar Crisps"
    credit = credit - 80
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 80 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase Mccoy's Cheddar Crisps"


End Sub

Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Pepsi Max, Please Insert £1.10"
    If credit >= 110 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing Pepsi Max"
    credit = credit - 110
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 110 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase Pepsi Max"


End Sub

Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Mountain Dew, Please Insert 99p"
    If credit >= 99 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing Mountain Dew"
    credit = credit - 99
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 99 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase Mountain Dew"

End Sub

Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Fanta, Please Insert £1.05"
    If credit >= 105 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing Fanta"
    credit = credit - 105
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 105 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase Fanta"

End Sub

Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Dr.Pepper, Please Insert £1.20"
    If credit >= 120 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing Dr.Pepper"
    credit = credit - 120
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 120 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase Dr.Pepper"

End Sub

Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Buxton Mineral Water, Please Insert 90p"
    If credit >= 90 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing Buxton Mineral Water"
    credit = credit - 90
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 90 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase Buxton Mineral Water"
End Sub

Private Sub Button14_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button14.Click
    credit = credit + 1
    TextBox1.Text = credit
End Sub

Private Sub Button21_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button21.Click
    credit = credit + 2
    TextBox1.Text = credit
End Sub

Private Sub Button20_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button20.Click
    credit = credit + 5
    TextBox1.Text = credit
End Sub

Private Sub Button19_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button19.Click
    credit = credit + 10
    TextBox1.Text = credit
End Sub

Private Sub Button18_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click
    credit = credit + 20
    TextBox1.Text = credit
End Sub

Private Sub Button17_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button17.Click
    credit = credit + 50
    TextBox1.Text = credit
End Sub

Private Sub Button16_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button16.Click
    credit = credit + 100
    TextBox1.Text = credit
End Sub

Private Sub Button15_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
    credit = credit + 200
    TextBox1.Text = credit
End Sub

Private Sub Button22_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button22.Click
    credit = 0
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    RichTextBox1.Text = "Credit has been returned"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If credit < 0 Then credit = 0
    TextBox1.Text = credit


    If credit >= 1000 Then credit = 1000
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit = 1000 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Maximum credit of £10"
End Sub

Private Sub Button23_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button23.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Monster Munch, Please Insert 90p"
    If credit >= 90 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing Monster Munch Crisps"
    credit = credit - 90
    TextBox1.Text = credit
    If credit < 90 Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase Monster Munch Crisps"


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING? No need to write titles in all caps.

Comment: sorry :) I am new to stackoverflow, it was recommended i make the title stand out so thats all that came to mind

Comment: If we will do your school work for you, you have no chance to become a programmer. You should think, how vending machine works. Draw your design, all the units, etc and code little by little.

Comment: I just needed some help, I didnt ask for the entire project to be created.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make it so it only displays that message if the credit is not
>   enough to buy the product before-hand and not straight away after the
>   purchase?

First off, you should always use an `End If` to close off your `If` statements, even if they only have one line in them.  Not doing so leads to subtle bugs where you think a "block" of code is running when the `If` statement is true, but only the first line is affected and the rest always run.

For your specific code, you're so close.  By adding an `Else` block, an `End If`, and reformatting the code, it becomes as simple as:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You Have Selected Galaxy Caramel, Please Insert 60p"
    If credit >= 60 Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = "Thank you for purchasing a Galaxy Caramel bar"
        credit = credit - 60
        TextBox1.Text = credit
    Else
        RichTextBox1.Text = "You do not have enough credit to purchase a Galaxy Caramel Bar"
    End If
End Sub
```

Obviously you need to change all of the items to follow the pattern above.

> Secondly, how would I go about making a system for the credit left
>   over after the purchase, as at the moment I have only got a credit
>   return button which the user would use to extract the remaining credit
>   left over after the purchase, instead of a system for giving out
>   change.

Not sure what you mean here.  Can you explain in  more detail what you want to happen?

> Finally, how would I make it so the user is not allowed to enter text
>   into a text-box as the vending machine uses two text box's, one to
>   display credit and the other to display other general messages such as
>   to clarify that you have bought a certain product or that you do not
>   have enough credit to purchase a certain product.

Both the TextBox and the RichTextBox have a ReadOnly() property you can set to True so that they cannot be changed by the user.  But since they are using the buttons only, and don't need to type at all, why not use a different control like Labels instead?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, much appreciated :) , what I meant by the second problem is that I do not know how I would programme a system that gives out change for the vending machine, and that instead as a temporary solution the user has to press credit return after their purchase to get their money. Also, one last question how do you transfer a windows form application project to a usb stick as when I try to open it from the usb stick it doesnt work and it displays an error message. Thanks! :)

Comment: Gotcha.  You could simply use another control to receive whatever is left over after a purchase.

Comment: (just to let you know I copy the project directly from the projects folder in the folder called visual studio 2010) it says "cannot find the file 'F:\Vending Machine.vb It may have been removed or deleted"

Comment: For just the executable, copy the files inside the "bin\debug" or "bin\release" folder.  All the other files are for editing the application itself in Visual Studio.

Comment: I have tried that, but I realized my teacher may need to see the actual code for the application just to check that I have not downloaded it from the web and maybe also if he needs to edit the code himself to make improvements

Comment: Hi again, I also have a binary addition console app I must create as-well, I am really stuck on that one so I would really appreciate it if you would help me out with that, thank you! : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662777/how-to-add-binary-numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use a State Machine for this scenario. Head First Design Patterns has a good example of Vending Machine using State Design pattern. Even though the book gives samples  in Java, you can still work out the concepts.

For calculating change, I wrote this block below. It takes in available coin inventory and change required and returns a boolean to indicate if all change can be returned. The method will attempt to return the maximum change possible with the given inventory.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method attempts to calculate required change from a given coin inventory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="coinInventory">Key is the denomination of coin and value is the available number </param>
    /// <param name="changeRequired">The change to count and return</param>
    /// <param name="updatedCoinInventory"></param>
    /// <param name="coinsToReturn"></param>
    /// <returns>True if changeRequired could be calculated, False if coinsToReturn represent less than changeRequired </returns>
    public bool GetChange(IDictionary<int, int> coinInventory, int changeRequired, 
                          ref IDictionary<int, int> updatedCoinInventory, 
                          ref IDictionary<int, int> coinsToReturn,
                          ref int amountDue) 
    {
        int changeOutstanding = changeRequired;

        updatedCoinInventory = coinInventory.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value); 

        coinsToReturn = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> coin in coinInventory)
        {
            if (changeOutstanding == 0) break;

            int numberOfAvailableCoins = coin.Value;

            while (changeOutstanding >= coin.Key && numberOfAvailableCoins >= 1)
            {
                if (!coinsToReturn.ContainsKey(coin.Key))
                {
                    coinsToReturn.Add(coin.Key, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ coinsToReturn[coin.Key];
                }

                changeOutstanding = changeOutstanding - coin.Key;

                -- updatedCoinInventory[coin.Key];
                -- numberOfAvailableCoins;
            }
        }

        amountDue = changeOutstanding;

        return changeOutstanding == 0;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.